# Angular property null at runtime

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control

I have the following setup:

```
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

 nummer: FormControl = new FormControl("", this.nummerValidator());

  firstname: FormControl = new FormControl("", [Validators.minLength(3)]);
  lastname: FormControl = new FormControl("", [Validators.minLength(3)]);

 formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    firstname: this.firstname,
    lastname: this.lastname,
  }, this.formGroupValidator());

 ngOnInit() {
  }

 nummerValidator() {
    return (control: FormControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
      if (this.checkEmpty(control.value)) {
        this.enableOnNumber();
        return null;
      }
      this.disableOnNumber();
      if (isNaN(control.value)) {
        return {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}};
      }
      return null;
    }
  }

 enableOnNumber() {
    this.firstname.enable();
    this.lastname.enable();
  }

  disableOnCardNumber() {
    this.firstname.disable();
    this.lastname.disable();
  }

formGroupValidator() {
    return (control: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
      //someStuffHere
      return errorFound ? {'formGroupError': true} : null;
    }
  }
```

When I run it this way and load the page, I get an error saying that `this.firstname` and `this.lastname` are null in the function `enableOnNumber`. Note that the function `disableOnNumber` works fine.

However, when I initialize the nummer FormControl without the validator and set the validator in the `ngOnInit` function everything works. Why is that? Any explanation?

Here's how it works:

```
nummer: FormControl = new FormControl();
ngOnInit() {
    this.nummer.validator = this.NummerValidator();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript 
and JavaScript is an interpreted language, not a compiled language an interpreter in the browser reads over the JavaScript code, interprets each line, and runs it

The `enableOnNumber()` method is called initially on Page load by the `nummerValidator()`  which associated with nummer control validation and since nummer form control is declared first its validation is called too.

Implement this below change.

```
  firstname: FormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(3)]);
  lastname: FormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(3)]);
  nummer: FormControl = new FormControl('', this.nummerValidator());
```

Since you are using firstname & lastname form control in nummer validation, it is better to declare this control first and then declare nummer form Control.

Not sure whether paybackNummerValidator() method uses firstname & lastname or the appropriate null check is added. Therefore this error is not thrown.

Comment: @Chry007 did this help you ? or you have any doubt ?